# Getting a rails test to pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, routes

Following a rails tutorial but when off on a slight tangent and now cant get a test to pass.
Below is my routes file and my test file. The `home` test is failing and this line `, to: "static_pages#home", as: "home"` is the line that makes it appear. i.e remove this and it'll pass. I was wondering why someone could explain why this is failing and how to alter the test to make it pass but keeping this line in?

My routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :static_pages
    get 'static_pages/help'
    get 'static_pages/test'
    get 'static_pages/home', to: "static_pages#home", as: "home"
    root 'application#hello'

end
```

My test file:

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "should get home" do
    get static_pages_home_url
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get help" do
    get static_pages_help_url
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get test" do
    get static_pages_test_url
    assert_response :success
  end


end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static_pages_home_url` is the default helper method for that route with controller `static_pages` and action `home` but you set the name as `home` so your test should be

```
test "should get home" do
  get home_url
  assert_response :success
end
```

Comment: ah amazing! so where i have the `as` keyword, I just change it to that. cheers! will accept answer in 5 mins